# Expo Facebook Login - How to redirect user without proxy?

Tags: facebook, expo, facebook-login, expo-auth-session

Expo announced that it migrates from using a proxy so for my development build I changed my code. So far I used proxy and it all worked fine. Now I changed it based on the migration from proxy (https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/auth-proxy-migration.md) and I get the error:

> No redirect uri in the params. no redirect present in uri

```
 const [request, response, promptAsync] = Facebook.useAuthRequest({
        expoClientId: EXPO_CLIENT_ID,
        scopes: ['public_profile', 'email],
        clientId: CLIENT_ID,
        redirectUri: AuthSession.makeRedirectUri({scheme: 'com.julia.app'}),
        responseType: ResponseType.Code,
    });
```

in facebook developer console I changed:

from  `https://auth.expo.io/@user/appname` which I used with the proxy to

`your-scheme://expo-development-client/?url=https://u.expo.dev/your-eas-build-project-id?channel-name=your-channel-name`to use without proxy.
with my data: `com.julia.app://expo-development-client/?url=https://u.expo.dev/123xxxxxxxxx?channel-name=main`

On facebook developer console, I cannot add the redirect stating NOT with https, so I cant start with my scheme (even though thats what expo says to do). so I added https:// before. Maybe thats whats causing the error? How else can I add it? I am very lost.
Any ideas would be amazing!!